# Does C++ list.erase(it, it) erase something? Where to find good references?

Tags: c++, list, web, erase

I mean in situation when the iterators point on same element.

On http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/ say "Removes from the list container either a single element (position) or a range of elements ([first,last))." and 
"first, last
Iterators specifying a range within the list container to be removed: [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the one pointed by last."

I totally don't know if I do everything wrong but for every part of my code I don't find needed information anywhere and when I want to test it by myself, I end in a situation, when I don't know what happened and after asking here and arguing for long hours I find something like "undefined behavior". So can someone help me faster, what is it now?

And I want to be better programmer and find out better source than cplusplus.com and cppreference.com, because they both suck, is there something better? I am getting crazier every day with this C++ (but I still think it's much better for speedy huge programs than Java or C), please help.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see? Create a list, get an iterator to the middle, call erase(), and see what the contents are afterwards.

Comment: @Lukas How about referring to the standard if you want reference ?

Comment: Why not fill the list, print it, call erase(it, it) and print the list again?

Comment: and: whats wrong with cplusplus.com or cppreference.com?

Comment: @Stargazer712 Because I won't be sure if it's not an undefined behavior like million times before or if it's done OK.

Comment: @Mahesh Where can I find the standard?

Comment: Just FYI, when you are a little more experienced, cplusplus.com is a godsend. I think you also need to look into iterators and general data structures more as I have a feeling that you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Evgeni Cplusplus.com and cppreference.com always have only basics of the problem I try to solve, but I need more information.

Comment: [Do not use cplusplus.com, use cppreference.com](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Standard's own definition of ranges (24.2.1p7, emphasis mine):

> Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges. A *range* is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. **A range `[i,i)` is an empty range**; in general, a range `[i,j)` refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element pointed to by `i` and up to but not including the element pointed to by `j`.

So assuming `it` is a valid iterator in or past-the-end of `lst`, the call `lst.erase(it,it)` erases an empty set of elements from `lst`.  That is, it does nothing.

Comment: I hope it's true and where can I find those "The Standard's own definition"s?

Answer (score 2):

I think to best answer your question you should think about how iterators work and why everything is passed in as [first, last) and not something else.

There are two core rules about iterators that you need to keep in mind. You can always increment one (that is to say, first++) and two iterators that point to the same element will always be equal. Knowing this you can loop over ANY range of iterators with the logic:

```
for(; first != last; first++)
{
}
```

So, if first and last are equal, nothing will happen. So if you call list.erase(it, it) nothing will be erased.

To put it in a more general form. Any range in STL where first == last is effectively empty.

Comment: OK, I thought it also, but how can you be so sure? Where is it written? You went through the list functions?

Comment: @LukasSalich No matter what the standard says, the best way to be sure is to write code, compile it, and run it.

Comment: @LukasSalich You can't be sure that your compiler implements the standard, either.

Comment: @Code-Guru And that's the problem :(

Comment: @LukasSalich Perhaps you need to clarify the question. Are you asking what *should* happen or what actually *does* happen? From the title, I believe you are asking the former. Perhaps an edit will help clarify that.